# How to rewrite a multivariate polynomial term without redundancies?

Tags: notation, sum

This is from an exercise found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) on page 60. My question is: what is meant by $\sum\limits_{i_1=1}^D\sum\limits_{i_2=1}^{i_1}...\sum\limits_{i_M=1}^{i_{M-1}}w_{i_1i_2...i_M}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}...x_{i_M}$? For instance, for $M=3$ with $D=4$ we get $$\sum\limits_{i_1=1}^4\sum\limits_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum\limits_{i_3=1}^{i_2}w_{i_1i_2i_3}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}x_{i_3},$$ but what are the first summations over? The first one for example can't be summed over just $i_3=1$ and $i_3=i_2$ because that wouldn't make sense, just as summing over $i_3=1,i_3=2,i_3=3,i_3=i_2$ wouldn't make sense either (in both these cases we get redundancies *and* the wrong number of terms, since the original redundant formula (1.133) gives $D^M=64$ terms while the new formula given above is supposed to give only 10). Eg $i_3$ summed over $1$ and $i_2$ would give $$
\sum\limits_{i_1=1}^4\sum\limits_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum\limits_{i_3=1}^{i_2}w_{i_1i_2i_3}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}x_{i_3}\\
\sum\limits_{i_1=1}^4\sum\limits_{i_2=1}^{i_1}w_{i_1i_21}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}x_1+w_{i_1i_2i_2}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}x_{i_2}\\
\sum\limits_{i_1=1}^4w_{i_111}x_{i_1}x_1x_1+w_{i_111}x_{i_1}x_1x_1+w_{i_1i_11}x_{i_1}x_{i_1}x_1+w_{i_1i_1i_1}x_{i_1}x_{i_1}x_{i_1}\\
$$
which is completely wrong; similarly when summing over $1,2,3,i_{M-1}$.

Comment: The summations are explicit: As $i_1$ ranges from $1$ to $4,$ $i_2$ ranges from $1$ to $i_1,$ *etc.*

Comment: What's between 1 and $i_1$? ie what's "?" in $i_2=1,i_2=?,i_2=?,...,i_2=i_1$?

Comment: This is standard [summation notation:](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=summation+notation) for instance, the leftmost sum has $i_1$ range over the set $\{1,2,3,4\}.$  You can have [Wolfram Alpha do it for you.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5Ba%5Ex+b%5Ey%2C+%7Bx%2C+1%2C4%7D%2C+%7By%2C+1%2Cx%7D%5D)

Comment: The double sum is taken first from the outside of course... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way of writing
$$
\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_M=1 \\ i_1\geq i_2 \geq \ldots \geq i_M}^D w_{i_1 i_2 \ldots i_M}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_M}
$$
Try listing the possible values of $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$ in the case where $M=3$ and $D=4$. You've got $(1,1,1)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(2,2,1)$, $\ldots$